# Formula Returning #Value Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula that will return with a "PASS" based a logic test with two variables, and "FAIL" if the cell is left blank.

Formula so far:

```
=IF(OR('FormValues'!G36,"NULL"),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the #VALUE! error and, still being quite new to excel formulas, I'm not really sure why.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After a quick re-evaluation, I realized I was missing something in the logic test, so I updated the formula as follows:

```
=IF(OR(I8='FormValues'!G36,"NULL"),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Sadly, this still returns the #VALUE! error.

Comment: so you want if I8 = 'FormValues'!G36 or I8 is blank you want PASS and if anything else Fail?

Comment: Cell I8 cannot actually be left blank; NULL is to be used to represent an absence of data without the cell remaining blank/empty. If the cell is left blank or entered data does not match the referenced cell from FormValues cell G36, it needs to fail.

Comment: So we only care if I8 = 'FormValues'!G36 because if `'FormValues'!G36` is `NULL` it will not equal I8 cannot be `NULL`?

Comment: `OR(logic check 1, logic check 2, ..., logic check n)`  in your updated formula, you are not checking "Null" against anything.  if you need to check is I8 is, then you need to put `I8="NULL"` for your second logic check in your OR function

Comment: You actually just helped me realize that the formula written as =IF(I8='FormValues'!G36,"PASS","FAIL") would suffice since NULL is acceptable data to enter into cell G36 on the FormValues tab and would then reflect as NULL in cell I8

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(OR(I8='FormValues'!G36,I8="NULL"),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Note the update to the OR Function